# Visualising genetic distance information from personal genetics sites

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, 23andme

I've been using 23andme.com it shows me a comparison with genetic relatives and lists our common relatives.  I have over 1000 3rd, 4th and distant cousins on 23andme.

Is there are way to make a graphical representation of this information that shows a network of distance relationships? I suspect that it would fall fairly neatly into clusters that represented each of my grandparents (barring too much consanguinity).

I am happy to use webservices, or scripting languages, but I thought that I would ask here first so that I don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tool quite a few genealogists use for visually displaying connected relationships in a graph is [NodeXL](https://www.smrfoundation.org/nodexl/). NodeXL Basic is a free addin-in for Microsoft Excel.

The first person to blog about using NodeXL for genealogy was Shelley Crawford in 2017. She describes all the steps she took to use NodeXL to visualize her Ancestry DNA matches. Shelley goes into a lot of detail. An index of her visualization posts is here: http://twigsofyore.blogspot.com/2017/07/visualising-ancestry-dna-matchesindex.html

This is one of Shelley's examples:
[image]

Shelley created the [Connected DNA](https://www.connecteddna.com/) website, where she will run NodeXL on your data for a fee and send you the results.

[DNADNA](https://dnadna.uk/) is a free to use software for genetic genealogy visualization. It also uses Excel, but instead of NodeXL uses the [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) graph visualizing platform:

[image]

Also, there is the online family tree and DNA site:  [Rootsfinder](https://www.rootsfinder.com/) which can produce visualizations of your DNA matches for you:

[image]

For other ideas on ways to visualize your DNA matches, see Robin Wirthlin's June 2019 article: [10 Ways to Group Your DNA Matches into Genetic Networks](https://familylocket.com/10-ways-to-group-your-dna-matches-into-genetic-networks/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is such feature directly on 23andMe site. But there is a lot of 3rd-party sites offering similar functionality. For example, I prefer [GEDmatch](https://www.gedmatch.com/login1.php) service. You download your 23andMe raw file and upload it to GEDmatch, and then you will be able to match against different users from others testing companies like FTDNA, Ancestry and so on. The only criteria is that that users must upload their data to GEDmatch too.

Maybe also Roberta Estes' article [Chromosome Browser War](https://dna-explained.com/2014/11/30/chromosome-browser-war/) will be interesting to you.